# Prevent race condition with RxJava asynchronous thread implementation

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, redis, rx-java

I am using spring framework StringRedisTemplate to update an entry which happen with multiple threads.

```
public void processSubmission(final String key, final Map<String, String> submissionDTO) {
    final String hashKey = String.valueOf(Hashing.MURMUR_HASH.hash(key));
    this.stringRedisTemplate.expire(key, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    final HashOperations<String, String, String> ops = this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash();
    Map<String, String> data = findByKey(key);
    String json;
    if (data != null) {
        data.putAll(submissionDTO);
        json = convertSubmission(data);
    } else {
        json = convertSubmission(submissionDTO);
    }
    ops.put(key, hashKey, json);
}
```

In this json entry looks below,

```
key (assignmentId) -> value (submissionId, status)
```

As seen in code, before update the cache entry, I fetch current entry and add the new entry and put them all. But since this operation can be do in multiple threads, there can be situation of race condition leads to data lost. I could synchronize above method, but then it will be a bottle neck for the parallel processing power of RxJava implementation where processSubmission method is call via RxJava on two asynchronous threads.

```
class ProcessSubmission{

@Override
    public Observable<Boolean> processSubmissionSet1(List<Submission> submissionList, HttpHeaders requestHeaders) {
        return Observable.create(observer -> {
            for (final Submission submission : submissionList) {            
                //Cache entry insert method invoke via this call
                final Boolean status = processSubmissionExecutor.processSubmission(submission, requestHeaders);
                observer.onNext(status);
            }
            observer.onCompleted();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> processSubmissionSet2(List<Submission> submissionList, HttpHeaders requestHeaders) {
        return Observable.create(observer -> {
            for (final Submission submission : submissionList) {
                //Cache entry insert method invoke via this call
                final Boolean status = processSubmissionExecutor.processSubmission(submission, requestHeaders);
                observer.onNext(status);
            }
            observer.onCompleted();
        });
    }

}
```

Above will call from below service API.

```
class MyService{    
public void handleSubmissions(){
    final Observable<Boolean> statusObser1 = processSubmission.processSubmissionSet1(subListDtos.get(0), requestHeaders)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
    final Observable<Boolean> statusObser2 = processSubmission.processSubmissionSet2(subListDtos.get(1), requestHeaders)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());                   
    statusObser1.subscribe();
    statusObser2.subscribe();
    }       
}
```

So handleSubmissions is calling with multiple threads per assignment id. But then per main thread is create and call two reactive java threads and process the submission list associate with each assignment.

What would be the best approach I could prevent redis entry race condition, while keep the performance of the RxJava implementation? Is there a way I could do this redis operation more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only using the `ops` variable to do a `put` operation at the end, and you could isolate that point which is where you need to synchronize.

In the short research that I did, I couldn't find if `HashOperations` is not already thread-safe).

But an example of how you could just isolate the part you're concerned about is to do something like:

```
public void processSubmission(final String key, final Map<String, String> submissionDTO) {
    final String hashKey = String.valueOf(Hashing.MURMUR_HASH.hash(key));
    this.stringRedisTemplate.expire(key, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    Map<String, String> data = findByKey(key);
    String json;
    if (data != null) {
        data.putAll(submissionDTO);
        json = convertSubmission(data);
    } else {
        json = convertSubmission(submissionDTO);
    }
    putThreadSafeValue(key, hashKey, json);
}
```

And have a method that is synchronized just for the `put` operation:

```
private synchronized void putThreadSafeValue(key, hashKey, json) {
    final HashOperations<String, String, String> ops = this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash();
    ops.put(key, hashKey, json);
}
```

There are a number of ways to do this, but it looks like you could restrict the thread contention down to that `put` operation.